# How can I make my BFS algorithm run faster?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

So I have a function that looks at a grid (2D array) and finds all the paths from the starting point to the end point. So far the algorithm works as intended and I get the values that I'm looking for.

The problem is that it takes forever. It can run over a 100 x 100 grid no problem, but once I get to a 10000 x 10000 grid, it'll take about 10 min to give back an answer, where I'm looking for maybe 1 min at most.

Here's what it looks like right now:

```
public void BFS(Point s, Point e){
        /**
         * North, South, East, West coordinates
         */
        int[] x = {0,0,1,-1};
        int[] y = {1,-1,0,0};

        LinkedList<Point> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        queue.add(s);

        /**
         * 2D int[][] grid that stores the distances of each point on the grid
         * from the start
         */
        int[][] dist = new int[numRow][numCol];
        for(int[] a : dist){
            Arrays.fill(a,-1);
        }
        /**
        * "obstacles" is an array of Points that contain the (x, y) coordinates of obstacles on the grid
        * designated as a -2, which the BFS algorithm will avoid.
        */
        for(Point ob : obstacles){
            dist[ob.x][ob.y] = -2;
        }
        // Start point
        dist[s.x][s.y] = 0;

        /**
         * Loops over dist[][] from starting point, changing each [x][y] coordinate to the int
         * value that is the distance from S.
         */
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){                                        
            Point p = queue.removeFirst();
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){                             
                int a = p.x + x[i];
                int b = p.y + y[i];
                if(a >= 0 && b >= 0 && a < numRow && b < numCol && dist[a][b] == -1){
                    dist[a][b] = 1 + dist[p.x][p.y];
                    Point tempPoint = new Point(a, b);
                    if(!queue.contains(tempPoint)){
                        queue.add(tempPoint);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Works backwards to find all shortest path points between S and E, and adds each
         * point to an array called "validPaths"
         */
        queue.add(e);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            Point p = queue.removeFirst();

            // Checks grid space (above, below, left, and right) from Point p
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
                int curX = p.x + x[i];
                int curY = p.y + y[i];

                // Index Out of Bounds check
                if(curX >= 0 && curY >= 0 && !(curX == start.x && curY == start.y) && curX < numRow && curY < numCol){
                    if(dist[curX][curY] < dist[p.x][p.y] && dist[curX][curY] != -2){ // -2 is an obstacle
                        Point tempPoint = new Point(curX, curY);
                        if(!validPaths.contains(tempPoint)){
                            validPaths.add(tempPoint);
                        }
                        if(!queue.contains(tempPoint)){
                            queue.add(tempPoint);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

So again, while it works, it's really slow. I'm trying to get a `O(n + m)`, but I believe that it might be running in `O(n^2)`.

Does anyone know any good ideas to make this faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An clear reason for the observed inefficiency are the comparisons `!validPaths.contains(tempPoint)` and `!queue.contains(tempPoint)` which are both O(n). To do these comparisons you should be striving for an O(1) comparison, which can be accomplished by using a special datastructure such as a [hash-set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) or simply a [bitset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html).

As it stands now, your implementation is clearly O(n^2) because of these comparisons.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I changed it to a hashSet like you said, and got rid of the `!queue.contains(tempPoint)` in both places as it was redundant (the if statement already does a check). And I can run a 10000 x 10000 with a start point of (1, 2) and an end point of (4000, 3000) in about 5 min. Unfortunately I run out of heap space if I do something like (1, 2) and (9500, 9500), but I don't know how to further help that issue.